# La puce à l'oreille

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, origine-ou-raison

D'où vient l'expression « avoir la puce à l'oreille » ? Je sais ce qu'elle veut dire mais je ne comprends pas le lien entre l'expression et sa signification.

Comment: L'expression date de 2023, quand les gens ont commencé à se greffer les composants de leur téléphone portable dans l'oreille, ce qui leur permettait d'être au courant de tout facilement sans que ça ne se remarque. Bien entendu, de nos jours, avec l'implant cranien, ça prête à sourire.

Comment: @jourbarc : Je pense que tu confonds avec l'expression "Avoir la puce DANS l'oreille"...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Claude Duneton y consacre cinq pages dans son excellent recueil d'explications d'expressions, tout justement nommé *[La puce à l'oreille](http://www.livredepoche.com/livre-de-poche-3055167-claude-duneton-la-puce-a-l-oreille.html) (Anthologie des expressions populaires avec leur origine)* (un petit livre en Poche ma foi très utile).

L'oreille n'est pas l'oreille pour rien : il y a longtemps eu une analogie faite entre un coquille et une oreille (de par leur forme ; Duneton cite les "[oreilles de mer](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haliotis)", parfois "oreilles de Vénus"), or la coquille est souvent elle-même associée au sexe féminin (pensons à la moule, largement sujet de grivoiseries en tous genres).

Avoir *la puce en l'oreille* signifiait donc avoir des démangeaisons intimes, souvent nocturnes, procurées par le désir sexuel.

Duneton cite (entre bien d'autres) La Fontaine:

> Fille qui pense à son amant absent
>   Toute la nuit, dit-on, a la puce à l'oreille

Le Panurge de Rabelais se perçait d'ailleurs l'oreille pour y mettre un anneau enchâssé d'une puce, afin d'exhiber sa volonté affirmée de se marier.

Mais des vers du XIVe siècle utilisent aussi cette expression au sens très fort de causer un tort violent et dont il est dur de se débarasser, de la même manière que si une puce se logeait réellement dans l'oreille de quelqu'un. Ce qui a pu être le cas bien souvent par le passé moins hygiénique où ces bestioles pullulaient !

Comment: "largement sujette de grivoiseries" ou "largement sujette *à* grivoiserie" ?

Comment: Merci. J'opte pour le correct masculin "sujet de", juste par esprit de contradiction. :)

Answer (score 6):

D'après [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/mettre-avoir-la-puce-a-l-oreille.php)

> Cette expression a changé de sens au cours des siècles.
>   Elle est attestée pour la première fois au XIIIe, sous la forme *mettre la puche en l'oreille*, à une époque où les petits parasites pullulaient, quel que soit le niveau social de leur hôte [...].Bizarrement, elle signifiait alors "provoquer ou avoir un désir amoureux" [...].
>
> Au XVIIe siècle, l'expression se transforme, le 'à' remplace le 'en' et, surtout, le sens devient "être inquiet, agité", comme pour quelqu'un qui aurait senti une puce venir se loger dans son conduit auditif et qui en craindrait les conséquences 'démangeatoires'.
>
> Parallèlement, dès le XIVe siècle, on évoquait déjà les oreilles qui sifflaient ou démangeaient lorsque quelqu'un était supposé parler de vous.
>
> C'est probablement l'association de ces bizarres démangeaisons [...] et de l'inquiétude de quelqu'un ayant la puce à l'oreille qui a donné le sens moderne de cette expression.